# Wifi link over water

Tags: wireless, point-to-point

As I've come to understand, water can interfere with wireless data links over vast bodies of water due to the signal reflecting off the water. What alternatives are there to transfer data wireless with an ok speed (e.g. ~50-100 mbit/s) over a mostly calm body of water with a distance of about 30 km? Or is satellite the most viable alternative?

Also, it's on a boat. One of the points.

Comment: You're problem is with using a comm system that requires an almost perfect line-of-sight. And at 30km, wifi *really* isn't what you want. (play with https://airlink.ubnt.com/#/ to see why.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try alcon wireless, or wave wifi. They tend to specialize in marine wifi connectivity. Satellite is ok, albeit expensive, as long as you're not doing any latency sensitive computing (VoIP, Internet gaming, etc)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response ! Will definitely look into them!

Comment: Product and resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.